# Simple question on a SQL create table

Tags: sql-server-2005, create-table

I was actually in process of creating a sample table in my test database when somehow I missed out on proper syntax and came up with this statement for create table -

```
CREATE TABLE A (id as INT, column1 as nvarchar(10))
```

and when I tried to execute this statement, I got the error below -

```
'nvarchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Altough, I found that I should not have used "**as**" in the column declaration and corrected it, I am now curious on why I got this error for only `nvarchar` and not for `INT`.
Also why this error instead of a incorrect syntax or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #A (id as INT)` on its own would give you a different error `Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AS` is used to define computed columns. Therefore SQL Server expects an expression here, and this "looks" like a function call.

[Computed columns info on MSDN for SQl Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, this is something new to me. I always thought "as" is for alias. This concept of computed columns, I can make use of it in many places in my project too.